# How can I update summaries of two preferences with the same key?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning java and android and I get stuck with this problem. I'd like to give the user a choice between writing down the section of the article in the news app (many options) and to quickly choose from few popular sections. That's why I have two preferences with the same key. And I'd like to update summaries in both of them, but I don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

```
public static class NewsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
            Preference topic = findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_topic_key));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(topic);
            Preference section = findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_section_key));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(section);
            Preference chooseSection = findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_choose_the_section_key));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(chooseSection);
            Preference orderBy = findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_order_by_key));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(orderBy);
        }
}
```

`Section` and `chooseSection` have different Strings given, but the key is the same and it updates only the first view summary on the screen. Can I fix that?

Comment: Change the string value in strings.xml file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't add that it's all about JSON data parsing. I can't change the value of string.xml because it's the key to Uri.Builder also. I tried to change the value of that String and using the section key instead of chooseSection key in uri builder (as they have the same value), but then data aren't updated after choosing the section by the user.